# How to get the key value output from RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Following is the RDD:

```
[(8, [u'darkness']), (2, [u'in', u'of', u'of', u'of']),
(4, [u'book', u'form', u'void', u'upon', u'face', u'deep', u'upon', u'face'])]
```

How do i print the keys and the value length for the above.

The output for above should be:
(key, no of words in the list)

> (8,1) (2,4) (4,8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` function to create a tuple of the key and number of words in the list:

```
data = sc.parallelize([(8, [u'darkness']), (2, [u'in', u'of', u'of', u'of']), (4, [u'book', u'form', u'void', u'upon', u'face', u'deep', u'upon', u'face'])])

data.map(lambda x:tuple([x[0],len(x[1])])).collect()
```